# Injectmocks unable to instantiate because No thread-bound request found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to create a logging utility in REST API and I would require some details from HttpServletRequest for the same.

Below is code for logging utility:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Component
@Scope(scopeName = "session",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoggingUtil {

    private String uri;
    private String callerIp;
    private String authorization;

    public LoggingUtil() {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = 
                ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        this.uri = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
        this.callerIp = httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
        this.authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
    }

    public void log() {
        System.out.println("URI is "+this.uri+" Caller IP is "+this.callerIp+"authorization id is "+this.authorization);
    }
}
```

I am trying for unit testing the class using JUnit-Mockito framework, but the test coverage always has the issue with InjectMocks not working properly.

Below is unit test case code :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.omg.CORBA.portable.ResponseHandler;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class LoggingUtilTest {

    @InjectMocks
    LoggingUtil loggingUtil;

    @Mock
    static HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Mock
    static MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        httpServletRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        request.setServerName("www.example.com");
        request.setRequestURI("/foo");
        request.setQueryString("param1=value1&param");
    }

    @Test
    public final void testLoggingUtil() {
        assertEquals(request.getRequestURI(),"/foo");
    }

}
```

Below is the error that is displayed in console :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'loggingUtil' of type 'class in.name.util.LoggingUtil'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.initMocks(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:53)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at in.name.util.LoggingUtil.<init>(LoggingUtil.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer$NoArgConstructorInstantiator.instantiate(FieldInitializer.java:195)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer.acquireFieldInstance(FieldInitializer.java:137)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldInitializer.initialize(FieldInitializer.java:91)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.PropertyAndSetterInjection.initializeInjectMocksField(PropertyAndSetterInjection.java:94)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.PropertyAndSetterInjection.processInjection(PropertyAndSetterInjection.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:68)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.relayProcessToNextStrategy(MockInjectionStrategy.java:89)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.relayProcessToNextStrategy(MockInjectionStrategy.java:89)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjection$OngoingMockInjection.apply(MockInjection.java:92)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultInjectionEngine.injectMocksOnFields(DefaultInjectionEngine.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:87)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processInjectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:48)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:42)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to propose following test.
Hope this helps:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class LoggingUtilTest {
    private LoggingUtil loggingUtil;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();

    @Before
    public void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        request.setRequestURI("/foo");
        request.setRemoteAddr("10.1.1.11");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "xAuth");
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));
        loggingUtil = new LoggingUtil();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testLoggingUtil() {
        String requestURI = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(loggingUtil, "uri").toString();
        assertEquals(requestURI,"/foo");

        String authorization = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(loggingUtil, "authorization").toString();
        assertEquals(authorization,"xAuth");

        String callerIp = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(loggingUtil, "callerIp").toString();
        assertEquals(callerIp,"10.1.1.11");
    }
}
```

Comment: @i-bondarenko This worked ! But why did you use ReflectionUtils in place of mocking objects

Comment: Added another variant with Mock. Have a look, please. Choose the best for you. By my opinion first one is better - more readable.

Comment: I use ReflectionTestUtils because it is simple and robust way to check final state of the tested object.

If one or both answers are fine for you, could you mark one of them or both as answered or useful, please. :)

Comment: It is throwing below error :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either targetObject or targetClass for the field must be specified
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118)
 at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.getField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:258)
 at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.getField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:212)
 at com.slb.schemaservice.util.LoggingUtilTest.testLoggingUtil(LoggingUtilTest.java:30)

Comment: I have just added github repository with demo project. You could clone it by https://github.com/ivan333m/mock.git and run LoggingUtilTestSimple.java and   LoggingUtilTestWithMocks.java. Let me know if you have any issue with it, please.

Comment: Thank! this works with springboottest + testcontainers + wiremock as of March, 2024. SpringBoot 2.6.7.

Answer (score 1):

One more variant with mocks (https://github.com/ivan333m/mock.git):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class LoggingUtilTest {
    private LoggingUtil loggingUtil;

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Before
    public void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(httpServletRequest));
    }

    @Test
    public final void testLoggingUtil() {
        when(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("/foo");
        when(httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()).thenReturn("10.1.1.11");
        when(httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization")).thenReturn("xAuth");
        loggingUtil = new LoggingUtil();

        String requestURI = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(loggingUtil, "uri").toString();
        assertEquals(requestURI, "/foo");
        String authorization = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(loggingUtil, "authorization").toString();
        assertEquals(authorization, "xAuth");
        String callerIp = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(loggingUtil, "callerIp").toString();
        assertEquals(callerIp, "10.1.1.11");
    }
}
```